# How do i form this replacement with regular expression

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to remove a particular string using php, the string needs to start with `<div class='event'>` followed by any possible string but which contains `$myVariable`, which is then followed by `</div>`. How do I remove all this using `preg_replace()`? I have worked out it might be something like this

```
preg_replace("<div class='event'>(.*)" . $myVariable . "(.*)</div>", "", $content);
```

But I cant get it to work.

Update:

I need to remove a `div` and everything inside it, the div contains an event name and date but I can only delete the div based on the events name and so the date needs to be defined as practically any string.

Comment: You won't get it to work with regex. Please precise what you are trying to achieve. Remove/replace some `<div>` tag contents? Or just retrieve some value? Please also provide a sample HTML fragment.

Comment: What does `$myVariable` contain?  Are you sure you need a regex here and not just a simple `str_replace()`?

Comment: If you have nested divs, you're better off with an html parser

Comment: I need to remove a div and everything inside it, the div contains an event name and date but I can only delete the div based on the events name and so the date needs to be defined as practically any string

Comment: Where is the event name? Please post a real-life HTML code as an example to see the sample structure of the HTML document you need to remove the `<div>` from.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to parse html with regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you have a `<div>` and inside it, there is some text node with a specific word you define with `$myVariable`.

The task is:

1. Read the document in
2. Initialize DOM
3. Collect the `<div>` tags with `.nodeValue` containing `$myVariable` text
4. Remove those tags from the DOM
5. Return updated DOM

The code for that algorithm is below (DOM is initialized with a HTML string in the demo):

```
$html = "<<YOUR_HTML_STRING>>"
$dom = new DOMDocument;               // Declaring the DOM
$dom->loadHTML($html);                // Initializing the DOM with an HTML string
$myVariable = "2015-09-12";           // Your dynamic variable

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);          // Initializing the DOMXpath
$divs = $xpath->query("//div[contains(.,'$myVariable')]"); // Collecting DIVs 
                                                           // having $myVariable
foreach($divs as $div) { 
   $div->parentNode->removeChild($div); // Removing the DIVs
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();                  //  Getting the updated DOM
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/9pqdkN)

Note that you can force DOMDocument to omit adding `!DOCTYPE` using the following to declare and initialize DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```